# Uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.. error: failed parsing overlays

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Facing problem while running  `./gradlew assembleRelease` to generate APK in react native.

> Error: Uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first
>   into .flat file.. error: failed parsing overlays

I already tried setting `android.enableAapt2=false`. It allows me to generate APK but unable to install APK in device using generated APK.

Actually I am using `react-native-camera` in application with following

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0',
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If disabling aapt2 didn't work for you, please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397028/4884617

Answer (score 3):

There's another option you can try in `gradle.properties` which is `org.gradle.configureondemand=true`. So use that instead of `android.enableAapt2=false`.

Run `./gradlew clean` after.

Comment: tried with org.gradle.configureondemand=true but still facing same

Comment: @MukeshJangid did you clean after adding it?

Comment: Maybe the best answer could be a solution not workaround.